# Sphinx. How fast are Random results?

Tags: database, database-design, sphinx

Does anybody have experience with getting random results from index with +100,000,000 (100 million) records.

The goal is getting 30 results ordered by random, at least 100 times per second.

Actually my records are in MySQL but selecting ORDER BY RAND() from huge tables is the most easiest way to kill MySQL.

Sphinxsearch or whatever what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have that big an index to try.

```
barry@server:~/modules/sphinx-2.0.1-beta/api# time php test.php -i gi_stemmed --sortby @random --select id
Query '' retrieved 20 of 3067775 matches in 0.081 sec.
Query stats:

Matches:
<SNIP>

real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.010s
```

This is on a reasonably powerful dedicated server - that is serving live queries (~20qps)

---

But to be honest if you dont need filtering (ie each query has a 'WHERE' clause), you can just setup a system that returns random results - can do this with mysql. Just using ORDER BY RAND() is evil (and sphinx while better at sorting than mysql is still doing basically the same thing).

How 'sparse' is your data? If most of your ids are used, can just do soemthing like

```
$ids = array();
$max = getOne("SELECT MAX(id) FROM table");
foreach(range(1,30) as $idx) {
   $ids[] = rand(1,$max);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$ids).")";
```

(may want to use shuffle() in php on the results afterwards as you likly to get the results out of mysql in id order)

Which will be much more efficient. If you do have holes, perhaps just lookup 33 rows. Sometimes will get more than need, (just discard), but you should still get 30 most of the times.

(Of course you could cache the '$max' somewhere, so it doesnt have to be looked up all the time.)

Otherwise you could setup a dedicated 'shuffled' list. Basically a FIFO buffer, have one thread, filling it with random results (perhaps using the above system, using 3000 ids at a time) and then the consumers just read random results directly out of this queue.

FIFO, is not particully easy to implement with mysql, so maybe use a different system - maybe redis, or even just memcache.